# Flutter build error output partly in german

Tags: flutter, gradle, build, error-messaging

My Flutter setup is the following:

[image]

The language of my OS (Windows 11) is set to German.
Now whenever I do a `flutter run` and get a build error, most parts of the error message are in English, other parts however, are in really clunky German.

[image]

I am looking for a way to get an english-only output. The problem is probably not Flutter per se but the underlying tool chain. It looks like parts of the error message are generated by Gradle.